# How remove axis lines in clustered bar chart using python-pptx?

Tags: python, python-pptx

This is the sample code that I have to produce the chart (image linked below).

```
x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(6), Inches(4.5)
graphic_frame = slide.shapes.add_chart(
    XL_CHART_TYPE.BAR_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data
)

chart = graphic_frame.chart

chart.chart_title.has_text_frame=True
chart.chart_title.text_frame.text= "1_TRS_Year"
chart.chart_style = 1
    
    
plot = chart.plots[0]
plot.has_data_labels = True
data_labels = plot.data_labels
    
data_labels.font.size = Pt(9)
data_labels.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0,0,0)
data_labels.number_format = '0%'
data_labels.position = XL_LABEL_POSITION.OUTSIDE_END

category_axis.has_major_gridlines = False
category_axis.has_minor_gridlines = False
category_axis.minor_tick_mark = XL_TICK_MARK.OUTSIDE
category_axis.tick_labels.font.italic = False
category_axis.tick_labels.font.size = Pt(12)
category_axis.tick_label_position = XL_TICK_LABEL_POSITION.LOW
    
    
value_axis = chart.value_axis
value_axis.has_major_gridlines = False
value_axis.has_minor_gridlines = False
    
value_axis.minor_tick_mark = XL_TICK_MARK.OUTSIDE
value_axis.tick_labels.font.italic = False
value_axis.tick_labels.font.size = Pt(12)
value_axis.tick_label_position = XL_TICK_LABEL_POSITION.LOW
```

[image: plot to remove axis line]

Comment: A link-to-a-picture-only answer with no explananation nor code attempt is not recommended.

Comment: i tried to change the color to white for it not to become visible. but should there be an another way?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this code will do what you're asking for:

```
chart.category_axis.visible = False
chart.value_axis.visible = False
```

If you want to hide the axis line but retain the tick-marks etc., try setting the width of the axis line to zero:

```
chart.category_axis.format.line.width = 0
```

Comment: i only wanted to remove the line (and keep the labels, tick marks etc), but chart.category_axis.format.line.width = 0 doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't remove the axis line, but makes it white, so it is also not visible anymore:

```
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor

category_axis.format.line.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 255, 255)
```

Comment: One other thing that might be worth trying Sander is `axis.format.line.fill.background()`, which is theoretically at least "no color". This works in some other contexts, like the border around a shape if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the axis line but retain the tick-marks etc., it will be like this:

```
chart.value_axis.format.line.fill.background()
chart.category_axis.format.line.fill.background()
```